# How to avoid ValueError and get integer only input in python2?

Tags: python, python-2.7

[image: python valueerror]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# getting user input
height = int(raw_input("height: "))

while (height < 0 or height > 23):
    height = int(raw_input("height: "))

# building the "pyramid"
spaceCount = height
hashCount = 1

for i in range(height):
    assert height != 0
    hashCount += 1
    spaceCount -= 1
    print " " * spaceCount,
    print "#" * hashCount
```

The code should keep prompting user if input is not an integer. But how?

Comment: Do not copy and paste images here.  Copy the code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch the exception.

```
 height = 24
 while (height < 0 or height > 23):
     try:
        height = int(raw_input("heightL "))
     except ValueError:
        print "Height needs to be an integer. Try again."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the input in an endless loop, waiting until the user enters a valid integer. For example:

```
while True:
  try:
    val = int(raw_input("Enter an integer:"))
  except ValueError:
    print "I said an integer"
  else:
    # ValueError was not thrown, which means the user entered a valid integer
    break
```